# Hide custom view whenever outside of custom view is clicked?

Tags: uiview, ios5.1

Hi I created Custom View with frame (244,75,142,85) an inside my custom view I have placed 2 UIButtons.But how to hide custom view  whenever I click outside of my custom view .If anyone know advise me  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add big button in outside view, Set the frame to the entire of the view. And in Touchupinside event, create method to hide the entire view.

Comment: thanks but i have tableview and custom view in my main view if I add button TableView interaction will be disabled right.Anyway thanks great idea.

Comment: Yes, but you can add the button behind all the views so that other view's functionality will not be affected.